# Powershell Pipe command; how to get all properties?

Tags: powershell

i think it is a really simple question for powershell experts,
but i found no results on google because i do not know the right keywords.
Here is the Question (Powershell):

Example:

```
Command-A | Command-B | Export-CSV result.csv
```

how to get all properties/columns from Command-A and B in the csv file?
On my case only the columns from Command-B were exported.

What i'm actually try is:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-ADPermission | Select-Object -Property (some columns from mailbox and adperms) Export-CSV result.csv
```

Thanks for help,
Best.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what commands you're actually trying to run?

Comment: What should happen in case the same column is present in both cmdlets? The question would really benefit from the real example, not `Command-X` one

Comment: @D-squared i added some information

Comment: @RobertDyjas good question, can i access/name them with Class.Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.1) with saving to variables should help with that. The example below contains `alias` property from `Get-Mailbox`. You can add more with the same method.

<sup>**NOTE**: Linebreaks added for visibility</sup>

```
Get-Mailbox -identity sometestmbx |
  Tee-Object -Variable mbx|
  Get-AdPermission |
  Select-Object identity, user, deny, isinherited, # From Get-AdPermission
  @{name="MbxAlias";e={$mbx.alias}} # Example property from Get-Mailbox
```

#### Explanation

`Tee-Object` is used to save the result of the first cmdlet to the variable. The object is then being sent down the pipeline so it can be used by `Get-AdPermission`.

In the `Select-Object` you use [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) and utilize the `$mbx` variable you filled before.

#### Limitation

The script won't work if `Get-Mailbox` returns more than one object. In that case, both objects will be saved to the variable. As a workaround, use a loop to iterate through the array of mailboxes.

Comment: Ok nice, thank you. But how can i get all properties, without specifying all the names, like select * in sql

Comment: is it possible something like: ... | foreach mbox.property x do @{name=x.name;e=x.val}

Comment: This is a good question, which, I think, might deserve a separate question. I have tried it with some help of `Get-Member -MemberType property | Foreach-Object` but still struggling to get it working